# reduce the signed apk size

Tags: java, android

in my app project the resource size is 1 mb but my apk size is 60mb
i have search many solution but cant find any solution to reduce my app size help me to reduce my app size.i have added the code of build.gradle.
i will be thankful to you if you help me to solve it .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

import com.android.build.OutputFile

def getVersionCode = { ->

    def code = project.hasProperty('versionCode') ? versionCode.toInteger() : 14

    println "VersionCode is set to $code"

    return code
}
def getVersionName = { ->

    def name = project.hasProperty('versionName') ? versionName.toString() : "1.6.1"

    println "VersionName is set to $name"

    return name
}
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
```

> // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release
>   builds, // but continue the build even when errors are found:

---

```
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        //versionCode getVersionCode()
        //versionName getVersionName()
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : 'baad408e-ec86-40b1-9c39-22e2873d0657',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'}
dependencies
{
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:5.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.50'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.4'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.7.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:vungle:6.4.11.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
    // Recommended: Add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.0.1'  
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta04'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'network.mysterium:mobile-node:0.22.1'
    implementation 'com.github.rasoulmiri:buttonloading:v1.0.8'
}
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(applyGoogleServicesIfNeeded)
}
task applyGoogleServicesIfNeeded {
    if (project.hasProperty('applyGoogleServices')) {
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Have you tried analyzing the size with https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer?

Comment: yes i have alreay try it

Comment: And...what was taking up all the space?

Answer (score 0):

you have added many dependencies which can be the reason of consuming space. remove unused dependencies. you can also check your drawable folder if you have icons or images, convert that to webp. and don't too much worry about apk size if it is 60 MB in .aab it will be round about 30 mb in playstore.